# Issue with Bootsrap and Tooltip plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using for my Web site Tooltip from Bootstrap. Everything is almost working fine but there is still a little issue that I am not able to fix.

Actually, I have a buttons nav bar and when I mouse hover one of them, this one moves to the left and the padding between the next button disappear.

Here, an example of what I mean : http://hpics.li/82e89ac

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Nouvel article">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
    </a> 
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Page d'accueil">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
    </a>    
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tableau de bord principal">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
    </a>    
</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Gestion des articles">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
    </a>
</button>

<script>
    $(function (){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            'placement': 'bottom'
        })
    });
</script>
```

I have tried on JSFiddle and it worked successfully : https://jsfiddle.net/mgjnhu17/

So, I do not understand why it works on JSFiddle and it does not work on my local.

Comment: This probably is your internal style problem set to the element. You need to identify with `inspect element` in browser!!

Comment: Hello, I only use Bootstrap and no personal stylesheet. I checked with Firebug and there is no padding attribut on .btn class so I do not understand !

Comment: Compare your code from browser styles to fiddle styles here! You might get some differences!

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it. Did you mean there is a real difference I do not see and this is why it does not work or it was a suggestion?

Comment: There is definitely some differences in `css` attached to the `tooltip/button` between fiddle here and your code in your system. You need to compare both to identify them.

Comment: How it would be different when I use exactly the same code ? Even if I try to compare both to identity the differences, I really don't get it !

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed my problem using Bootstrap's rows and tablet class like this :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
        // My buttons
    </div>
</div>
```

I hop it will help someone else !